# A question about theorem 2 in de Bruijn's 1950 paper "The roots of trigonometric integrals"

Tags: fourier-series, riemann-zeta

Theorem 2 of de Bruijn's paper titled "The roots of trigonometric integrals" (Duke Math. J., 17 (1950)) is given by:

[image: Theorem 2 de Bruin (1950)]

What does it mean by "the function $q(x)$ be regular in the sector...?

Does it only mean that there is no poles for $q(x)$ in this sector?

ADDED:
If we set $N=1,p_1=p_{-1}=\frac{1}{2}a (a>0)$, 
$q(x)=\left( \frac{1}{2}(x+x^{-1})\right)^{-m} (m=1,2,3...)$, $x=e^t$, then the integral becomes the one represented in another question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/812544/an-integral-that-might-be-related-to-the-modified-bessel-function-of-second-kind).

Is this $q(x)$ function regular in the sector $-\frac{\pi}{2}<\arg x<\frac{\pi}{2}$ and on its boundary?

I think that this $q(x)$ function is regular in the sector but not on its boundary, because when $-\frac{\pi}{2}=\arg x =\arg (e^t)=-i t$ we have $\cosh(t)=\cos(it)=0$. Therefore $Q(t)=q(e^t)=(\cosh t)^{-m} $ has a simple pole and does not have Taylor expansion at $t=-i\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Am I right?

Thanks- 
mike

Comment: "Regular" just means "holomorphic" in this context.

Comment: @AntonioVargas Thanks a lot for the answer!

Comment: @AntonioVargas [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/812544/an-integral-that-might-be-related-to-the-modified-bessel-function-of-second-kind)