# Fourier transform of exp(cos)

Tags: fourier-analysis

How do I calculate the Fourier transform ($t \rightarrow \omega$) of the following:

$\exp(A\cos(\omega_0 t))$

$A$ is a real constant, and $\omega_0$ is a real and positive constant. I know that this gives a Bessel function, but how can I show this?

Comment: What do you mean about reputation? There's no reputation requirement to tag a question.

Comment: @user61527 Apologies

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. Does the frequency variable $\omega$ really appear in the function that you want to transform or is that perhaps a typo?

Comment: @HansEngler No, not a typo. The $\omega$ is a constant. I'll rename it $\omega_0$ if you prefer.

Comment: You could try to show that the Fourier transform satisfies a suitable differential equation. Of course there is the small issue of convergence of the Fourier integrals.

Comment: The Fourier transform of this function does not exist in the usual sense since this function is not in any $L^1$. It has to be evaluated distributionally. Why do you think it gives a Bessel function as an output?

Comment: According to Abramowitz and Stegun's _Handbook of Mathematical Functions_, it is a Bessel function...

Comment: Can you please provide the claim by the authors? I am very skeptical of this.

Answer (score 0):

The modified Bessel Function of second kind $K_z(a)$ can be expressed as a Fourier transform [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/812544/an-integral-that-might-be-related-to-the-modified-bessel-function-of-second-kind):

$$K_{z}(a)=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp(-a\cosh t)\cosh(zt){\rm d}t=K_{-z}(a)$$

Comment: I would say this is related for sure, but this integral is at least well-posed. OP's is not. The function OP is interested in is very, very badly behaved with regards to the Fourier transform. Unless of course $\cosh$ is meant instead of $\cos$...

Comment: Only to the extent that $cos$ itself is "badly behaved" with regards to the Fourier transform. I don't think just being a Dirac comb is sufficient for that...